# Page Load Time - "Waiting on..." taking ages. What part of page request process is hung?

Tags: page-speed

I have a new cluster site running on Magento that's on a development server that is made up of 2 x web servers and 1 x database server.

I have optimized the site in all areas I know (gzip, increasing php memory limits, increasing database memory limits etc) but sometimes the page loading gets stuck on 'waiting for xxx.xx.xx.xxx' (Chrome and other broswers, chrome just shows it that way). It can sit there for 40 + seconds, sometimes it just never loads and I close it in frustration.

What part of the page loading process is this hung at? Is it a server issue, database issue, platform issue?

I need to know where to start or whether to push the hosting provider about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From prior experience, Magento seems to like to dance over the database quite a bit -- every time it does, (as the new MediaWiki seems also to do) it has to wait for the disk to be seek, read, and report, taking time from the end-user and memory from the server. See this link for caching ideas: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netresearch/extension/2138/catalogcache and also make sure MySQL has it's cache turned on and with VERY high memory values assigned to it. You'll also find a great improvement by having a multi-core CPU, of a high clock rate. Small virtual servers are NOT ideal for using Magento.

As I've suggested countless times before to other people, you ought to try http://tools.pingdom.com/ to see if your problem is based on DNS or the server itself. You may want to run a MySQL performance test and see any red-highlighted values and fix those if possible.

Comment: Thanks, what would you consider 'very high' memory values for mysql. My arrangement is on all three systems is Dual-core CPUs, 2gb ram, 60gb hdds, Ubuntu 12.04.
Apache, PHP5 and Magento running on the webservers and Mysql on the db server.

Comment: @James - I'll get back to you on that. But in the meantime, if you have PHPMyAdmin installed, go to the "Status" tab and look for any red numbers or notices saying "not ideal" and adjust accordingly.